# How to work with big numbers in PHP?

Tags: php, biginteger

How to work with big numbers in PHP?

such as

```
(6*27^0+17*27^1+11*27^2+18*27^3+25*27^4+4*27^5)^65537
```

Comment: I think this number will fit in a normal int. Okay, that was before you put the ^65537 at the end.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211345/working-with-large-numbers-in-php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can go for **[BCMath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)** to work with big numbers.

Answer (score 4):

GMP's actually faster than BCMath for bigintegers if you have it installed.  If you have neither BCMath or GMP installed you can use [phpseclib's pure-php biginteger implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net).

That implementation uses GMP or BCmath if they're available, in that order, and it's own internal implementation otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options:

- The GMP extension
- The BCMath Extension
- Litipk PHP BigNumbers ( https://github.com/litipk/php-bignumbers )
- Flourish Numbers ( http://flourishlib.com/docs/fNumber )

Answer (score 1):

Given the question title, I'm assuming that the OP meant `^` as a power operator and not PHP's [XOR operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php), although the actual numbers make me doubt.

This can be achieved using the [Brick\Math](https://github.com/brick/math) library (*disclaimer: I authored it*):

```php
use Brick\Math\BigInteger;

// Not using BigInteger just yet as the numbers are small, although we could
$value =  6 * 27 ** 0
       + 17 * 27 ** 1
       + 11 * 27 ** 2
       + 18 * 27 ** 3
       + 25 * 27 ** 4
       +  4 * 27 ** 5;

echo BigInteger::of($value)->power(65537); // 529970661615774734826076722083948398443...
```

I'm sparing you the rest of the 514566 digits :)

Comment: I meant power operator.