# How to save massive numbers in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I want Pi to like 100,000,000 decimals/digits.

And variables (well for me) say they have a limit of 67,000,000 bytes. Is there any way around this?

Can you save the first 10,000 characters/digits into one? Can you save it into an array 10,000 in each?

Is there a way?

Comment: I tried this once and broke stuff. I think the calculation itself was the issue. Splitting it into multiple strings / arrays still requires saving it. Can you post the code you're using to calculate?

Comment: Check the top answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211345/working-with-large-numbers-in-php

Comment: I'm just doing $number3 = bcsub($number1, $number2, 10000);  -But i want the 10,000 to be 100,000,000 but it doesn't let me -due to variable being to big :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're dealing with a buffer of that size, I'd save it to disk somewhere instead of keeping it in memory. Use `fwrite` and friends to save to a temporary file, and read it back when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

For dealing with very large numbers of arbitrary sizes you should use the [BCMath library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php).  The only limit is the amount of memory available.