# Working with big integer values

Tags: php

I have a code which works well up to 10 million i.e. 10,000,000 but stops working for higher value. Is there anyway to work with extremely large numbers in PHP

```
<?php
    $num_value_string;
    $counter=0;
    for($i=1;$i<=100000000;$i++)
    {
        $num_value_string=(string)$i;
        if(strstr($num_value_string,"17"))
            $counter++;
    }
    echo $counter . " numbers between 1 to " . --$i . " contains 17";
?>
```

Comment: There are much easier ways to solve this problem without spending hours to days in a for-loop.

Comment: I want to work on all values between 1 and 100,000,000....my code searches for 14 existing anywhere in the number

Comment: can you pls tell me any method to achieve this p.s.w.g

Comment: i want to count all the number between 1-100,000,000 containing 14 anywhere in them

Comment: Try to think about it mathematically rather than algorithmically. How many ways are there of arranging *n* digits such that a certain sequence of digits appears somewhere in the larger sequence? Once you think you've solved it mathematically you can use this simple method with smaller numbers to check your solution.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740573/extremely-large-integers-in-php

Comment: but simple php alone can handle numbers like 100,000,000 when I tried to execute $str=(string)100000000;  echo $str    it works perfectly.....or when i try to echo 100000000+1 ......it also works perfectly......then where is the problem

Comment: Are you executing this script in the browser and having timeout ?

Comment: Yes I am executing this in a browser....but there is no information about timeout....how to check for a timeout happening?

Comment: I executed the loop for($i=1;$i<=100000000;$i++){} echo $i and it printed the value of $i perfectly. I also tried if(strstr("1200000000","12")) echo "found" else echo "not found" and this also worked. I also tried converting a large number to string like $str=(string)12000000000 echo $str and it printed the string perfectly......so when all the parts are working perfectly individually....why the code is not working when these small parts are combines????

Comment: I guess it's timeout or memory limit issue. Check my answer below

Comment: well thanks webNeat....no heavy BC or GMP needed....simple solution worked for me....thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Looking at your code, PHP can handle these numbers without extra things. So your issue is timeout or memory limit. Try Setting this at the start of your script

```
ini_set("memory_limit","256M"); // very large !
set_time_limit ( 3600 ); // one hour is more then enough !
```

By the way, your problem could be solved more simply then that !

Comment: working perfectly.....u gave the ultimate solution....sometimes we don't need very deep programming tricks....simple things works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Except that this just hides the underlying problem with your code. It is not "the ultimate solution".

Comment: This was just to show you what is the problem. But your actual solution to the problem is not simple; Sure it's simple when writing it but it's very slow and use huge memory which is not good at all. If your script needs `5 minutes` to answer for `max = 10^8` it will need `500 minutes` for `max = 10^10` or even more. You should think about that.

Comment: may be u r right..... but it worked for me and this is a code just to experiment...not a part of any big real world problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use appropriate library for big number (e.g. [BC Math](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php)), but usually this is used to compute calculation on numbers, not as variable in a (long) loop.