# How can I handle long numbers that are provided as string while integer is expected?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a route that expects a weight as an integer.

```
#[Route(
    path: '/calculateMinMaxPrice/{price}/{weight}',
    name: 'add_book_calculate_min_max_price',
    options: ['expose' => true],
    defaults: ['weight' => 500]
)]
public function calculateMinMaxPrice(Request $request, float $price, int $weight = 500): JsonResponse
{/* do stuff */}
```

Now I found a case where a large number is provided for the "weight" parameter, as example: 61000012400004570000

This throws an uncaught error: Argument #3 ($weight) must be of type int, string given

I can't find a way how to safely handle this case. Is there a possibility to fetch that and handle it, e.g. by setting it to a default value?

I'm guessing that the value is provided as string, because the value is over the PHP_INT_SIZE value.
Currently I'm working with PHP8.1 and Symfony 5.4.

Comment: What weights are you processing here - planets? That is an enormous number...

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Obivously not. But I don't know how that adds value to the question. Can't validate the weight if I can't get to the validation.

Comment: Why dont you just replace the int type with mixed or remove it?

Comment: @KhorneHoly Maybe we need to figure out how come `61000012400004570000` was given as an input parameter for weights, than trying to deal with the types here.

Comment: excuse the brevity of the comment but the size of that number is so large that it seems unfeasible if it is intended to be a weight - but perhaps [this might be of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740573/extremely-large-integers-in-php) which mentions both bcmath and GMP though I agree with the comment by @nice_dev above

Comment: @CodeSpirit because I want my software as strongly typed as possible. But it would be a possible solution for this. Receiving such large numbers is not desired.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius it is coming from user inputs. I sadly cannot completely verify and validate the input on the client site of things (I will try what I can, but never trust a client), so I should look for a final solution on the server side. The weight is measured in grams and basically everything between 5000 and 30000 is an absolute exception, normal inputs are between the hundreds and low thousands. Everything about 100,000 can be dealt as an error.

Comment: @KhorneHoly Then `int` is wrong all along because URLs are strings. You wont circumvent this in any way. If you need proper type hinting use a union type or doc comments to describe it. You cant just put user input in a type hinted var without proper validation before.

Comment: agreed that you can never trust input provided by the user but knowing now more of the puzzle does suggest certain possible courses of action in processing the data. As you mention anything above 100,000 is an error you can test for that, reject it and warn the user

Comment: Thank you both for your input. Thought that this might be a more known issue with a "simple solution" that I just couldn't find. I changed up the type to `int|string` and added a validation in the controller, which can handle such inputs now. Please add an answer so that I can accept that. - Honestly though the calculation of planet weights does sound more interesting than plain unwanted user inputs. :-D

Comment: You could use `float`, too, because it has a much larger range.

Comment: 19 digits max for 64bit systems (~9 Quintilian). Make the type a string, that's what it is anyways from the URI. Then do your checks and convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to use custom [ValueResolver](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/value_resolver.html#managing-value-resolvers). It may not be available in Symfony 5.4, but most likely ArgumentValueResolverInterface will be available. Here's an example:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Resolver;

use InvalidArgumentException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ArgumentValueResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\ControllerMetadata\ArgumentMetadata;

class SafeIntArgumentResolver implements ArgumentValueResolverInterface
{
    public function supports(Request $request, ArgumentMetadata $argument): bool
    {
        return $argument->getType() === 'int';
    }

    public function resolve(Request $request, ArgumentMetadata $argument): iterable
    {
        $value = $request->attributes->get($argument->getName());

        // feel free to change the logic to suit you
        if (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false) {
            yield (int) $value;
        }
        elseif ($argument->hasDefaultValue()) {
            yield $argument->getDefaultValue();
        }
        else {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid or too long int value ('{$argument->getName()}': $value)");
        }
    }
}
```

```yaml
# config/services.yaml
services:
    App\Resolver\SafeIntArgumentResolver:
        tags:
            - { name: controller.argument_value_resolver, priority: 100500 }
```

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class ExampleController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route(
        path: '/calculateMinMaxPrice/{price}/{weight}',
        name: 'add_book_calculate_min_max_price',
        options: ['expose' => true],
        defaults: ['weight' => 500]
    )]
    public function calculateMinMaxPrice(Request $request, float $price, int $weight = 500): JsonResponse
    {
        return $this->json(['weight' => $weight]);
    }
}
```