# Printing big numbers in PHP

Tags: php, printf, number-formatting

The number is `13911392101301011` and regardless of using `sprintf` or `number_format` i get the same strange result.

```
sprintf('%017.0f', "13911392101301011"); // Result is 13911392101301012
number_format(13911392101301011, 0, '', ''); // Result is 13911392101301012

sprintf('%017.0f', "13911392101301013"); // Result is 13911392101301012
number_format(13911392101301013, 0, '', ''); // Result is 13911392101301012
```

Comment: Random idea: Is the number being interpreted as a `float` or `double` and rounded to the nearest valid value of such a data type? Noticed that it's too large to fit in a 32 bit integer, it could fit in a 64 bit integer though but not sure if it is.

Comment: I know that's too large, But i found using `sprintf` or `number_format` should solve the problem. Unfortunately not working in this case

Comment: Interesting that `13911392101301014` is being printed correctly and `13911392101301011` is not, so its not a range issue

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ Yes, That's the most strange thing to me too. When you try to echo `13911392101301015` the problem exists again and result is `13911392101301016`

Answer (score 1):

As you actually have the number as a string, use the `%s` modifier:

```
sprintf('%s', "13911392101301011"); // 13911392101301011
```

Note that PHP is using a signed integer internally. The size depends on your system.

32bit system:

```
2^(32-1) = 2147483648
```

64bit system:

```
2^(64-1) = 9223372036854775808
```

`-1` because 1 bit is reserved for the signage flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can do easily this way :-

```
ini_set("precision",25); // change 25 to whatever number you want or need 
$num = 13911392101301011;
print $num;
```

Comment: Still the same: `13911392101301012`

Comment: no,i have tested it.it works and of course BCMath is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with large numbers here, you may want to keep them as strings and perform numerical operation on the string values using [BCMath functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php).

```
$val = "13911392101301011";

echo $val; // 13911392101301011
echo bcadd($val, '4'); // 13911392101301015
echo bcmul($val, '2'); // 27822784202602022
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation states that $number in number_format [is float](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) so there is explicit typecast. Equivalent would look like this:

```
sprintf('%017.0f', (float) "13911392101301011");
```

Float is precise to around [14 digits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) and your number has 17 digits.

Answer (score -1):

Your number_format call is setting the . and , to blank

```
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = '.' , string $thousands_sep = ',' )
```

try this:

```
number_format(13911392101301011, 0, '.', ',');
```

Comment: The result is `13,911,392,101,301,012`

Comment: Isn't that what you're trying to do? Oh, your issue is the "rounding" of the last digit either up or down. What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Wrong answer. The OP is not trying to format the number, but to print its value as it is stated.

Comment: No friend. When i echo the number directly, The result is `1.3911392101301E+16`. Using `number_format` was a solution to solve this problem.

Comment: Check out some of the answers and comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936062/why-is-my-number-value-changing-using-number-format