# PHP number_format displaying incorrectly

Tags: php, number-formatting

New to programming and taking a PHP course. I wrote a very small program to test out the number_format function. Here is my code:

```
$num = 9876543210123456789; 
$result = number_format($num);
echo = $result;
```

The output is: 9,876,543,210,123,456,512

I'm sure it has something to do with the length of $num. But haven't been able to find the exact explanation/reason why this happens.

Comment: number_format — Format a number with grouped thousands. so what is incorrect?

Comment: What do you expect from the number format? It's to format the number with decimal places, thousand places, and the thousand separator. Please refer to the php manual.

Comment: This question is not about commas, please read again. What they are confused about is why the output number is different from what they input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeig a different number because the number you have provided is large enough to cause an overflow on your system. Try with a smaller number

```
<?php
$num = 9876543210123; 
$result = number_format($num);
echo  $result;                    // will show as expected, with formatting
```

Even if you don't use `number_format` on that number, your number will still cause overflow. Try this

```
$num = 9876543210123456789; 
echo  $num;   // not what you see above
```

**Also see:**

[What's the maximum size for an int in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670662/whats-the-maximum-size-for-an-int-in-php)

[PHP Integers and Overflow](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is exactly what I figured. Also thank you for the links to the manual. I should have looked there first but nonetheless, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass large numbers to the `number_format()` function. If you just need to format the number, you can write your own function to separate the numbers with a comma taking 3 by 3.

Reason is that if you check the manual, the number format takes the first parameter as a float. You need to have a good understanding about `float`, and `ints` to understand why it happens.

Here is something interesting I found in SO, it is same as your question, and it has a good answer. Please check it.

[Why is my number value changing using number_format()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936062/why-is-my-number-value-changing-using-number-format)