# Increment a large integer

Tags: php

I'd like an incremented `$max_id` to be returned.

Seems that the following script doesn't work:

```
<?php
$max_id = 656886639189471232;
$max_id = $max_id+1;
$max_id = number_format($max_id, 0, '', '');
var_dump($max_id);
?>
```

Needed `656886639189471233`

Comment: What does it return instead?

Comment: Switch to 64-bit PHP

Comment: @MTCoster returns string(18) "656886639189471232". I need string(18) "656886639189471233"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$a = "656886639189471232";
$b = "1";

echo bcadd($b, $a,0);
?>
```

If your input data are integers you can convert `$a` and `$b` to string with:

```
$var=5;
$tostring = strval($var);
echo var_dump($tostring);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is number_format is made for float.

You can have details on this other post [Why is my number value changing using number_format()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936062/why-is-my-number-value-changing-using-number-format)

Answer (score -1):

Remove the following line:

```
$max_id = number_format($max_id, 0, '', '');
```

The following works fine:

```
$max_id = 656886639189471232;
$max_id = $max_id+1;
var_dump($max_id);
```

Comment: That was a mistake, removed it.

Comment: It does returns the value you want.

Comment: `float 6.5688663918947E+17` this is what I get.