# Converting an int that is more than 16 digits long into a string in php

Tags: php, string, parsing, int, type-conversion

Is there any function that easily echos an integer that is 15+ digits long?
The only way I've managed is like this:

```
$num = 123456789012345;
$num = number_format($num);
$num = str_replace(',', '', $num);
echo $num;
```

But even this way it is only accurate up to 17 digits. After the 16th digit the number isn't printed accurately (because as a float it starts getting inaccurate - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936062/why-is-my-number-value-changing-using-number-format)).

> EDIT: From the answers below I wrote `ini_set('precision',40);` and then echoed $num straight. All this did was to, simply put, not show the decimal point in the float number. And again after the 16th digit it starts getting inaccurate. 
>   I also tried the other suggestion of changing it into an array and then iterating through it with `str_split($num);` and again the numbers were inaccurate from the 17th digit on!

The simplest solution would be to convert the integer into a string. I've tried:

```
$num = (string)$num; 
//and
$num = strval($num);
```

But neither change anything and they act as if as they remained as an int??

My question is specifically why are the conversions into strings not working. Is there a way to turn the number into a string? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I can think of is changing the precision of floats in the php.ini

```
ini_set('precision', 25);
```

I don't know where you get those large numbers from, but I'd suggest a look into [bc functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) too!

The last thing I thought of is using the explode function to split the string into an array and interate through it.

**EDIT:** When all suggestions failed, your only choices are to check out the [BC Math](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) and/or [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) functions as well as [MoneyMath](https://github.com/ikr/money-math-php). The [BigInteger](http://pear.php.net/package/Math_BigInteger) package should also do the trick, which uses GMP and BC.

Comment: thanks, I tried your suggestions... Check out the edits I made

Comment: @Ben Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, you see, it's not an "int" as you claimed :)

```
echo PHP_INT_MAX; // echoes 9223372036854775807
$n = 9223372036854775807;
echo $n; // echoes 9223372036854775807

$n = 9223372036854775808; 
echo $n; // echoes 9.2233720368548E+18
```

Setting `precision` to something greater, [as manniL said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35248283/2044039), does the trick.

```
ini_set("precision", 50);
$n = 9223372036854775808; 
echo $n; // echoes 9223372036854775808
```