# Large numbers in PHP are not what they seem to be

Tags: php

I agree with this

```
php > var_dump(number_format(10000000000000000000000)); // 10^22
php shell code:1:
string(30) "10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000"
```

What's happening here?

```
php > var_dump(number_format(100000000000000000000000)); // 10^23
php shell code:1:
string(30) "99,999,999,999,999,991,611,392"
```

Can someone explain to me what exactly is going on here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my number value changing using number\_format()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936062/why-is-my-number-value-changing-using-number-format)

Answer (score 3):

This is well-described in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow):

> ### Integer overflow
>
> If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the [integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) type, it will be interpreted as a [float](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) instead. Also, an operation which results in a number beyond the bounds of the [integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) type will return a [float](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) instead.
>
> #### Example #3 Integer overflow on a 64-bit system
>
> ```
> <?php
> $large_number = 9223372036854775807;
> var_dump($large_number);                     // int(9223372036854775807)
>
> $large_number = 9223372036854775808;
> var_dump($large_number);                     // float(9.2233720368548E+18)
>
> $million = 1000000;
> $large_number =  50000000000000 * $million;
> var_dump($large_number);                     // float(5.0E+19)
> ?>
> ```

There are many values that floating-point numbers can't exactly represent. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/354577) for details.

The [`PHP_INT_MAX` constant](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) shows the largest integer your version of PHP supports.

Answer (score 0):

[Floating point numbers.](http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/)

Computer memory is limited, so storing an infinitely precise integer value is impossible. Your system basically ran out of room for precise integer valuation.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875583/set-precision-for-a-float-number-in-php) does a great job talking about how to get the integer to appear at the number you want it though.

Answer (score 0):

Change the precisiona in php.ini or use ini_set and apply cast in your var

```
ini_set('precision', 2048);
$number1 = (float) "0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001";
$number3 = (float) "0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001";

$test1 = (0 == $number1);
$test2 = (0 == $number3);
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?