# strange issue on my server- big int get converted to exponetial

Tags: php, apache, api, twitter, server

I have a strange issue on my server. BigInt gets converted to exponential format.

```
echo '12345678912345678911';
output
1.2345678912346E+19
```

these are tweets id's returned by twitter api , it works fine on one server but for some server it get converted to exonetial format can i do something via php.ini to fix it
I want it in string format only. Please help me.

Comment: How do you store it? In a database? And how do you retrieve it?

Comment: i want 12345678912345678911 as output in string format

Comment: OK, I see - this answers your question -> [**PHP: How to convert bigint from int to string?**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7151387/1407478)

Comment: same code works fine on other server , can i do something via php.ini