# PHP bcmod or gmp_mod input type issue

Tags: php, gmp, bc

I'm using bcmod and gmp_mod functions in php for handling large numbers.

This works fine:

```
// large number must be string
$n = "10000000000000000000001";
$y = 1025;
$c = 1025;
// Both works the same (also tested in python)
$y = gmp_mod( (bcpowmod($y, 2, $n) + $c) , $n);
$y = bcmod  ( (bcpowmod($y, 2, $n) + $c) , $n);
```

But the input `$n` is not static. So I must use *type casting* like:

```
$n = (string)10000000000000000000001;
```

This **doesn't work** anymore.

for *gmp* gives this error:

```
gmp_mod(): Unable to convert variable to GMP - string is not an integer
```

And about *bc*, gives me this error:

```
bcmod(): Division by zero
```

The problem is, `(string)` doesn't convert it to string fine. Any idea?

**Edit:** I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7151387/4055329), but still the input is string:

```
$bigint = gmp_init("9999999999999999999");
$bigint_string = gmp_strval($bigint);
var_dump($bigint_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

If You are taking an input for `$n` it would give you as a `string` not as `int` and if you have type casted as `int` at any point ... taking care the max size of int,  the above given no is converted to `1.0E+22` now what happens  when you try to type cast `(string)1.0E+22` it becomes `"1.0E+22"` which is obviously just a string and can not be converted to gmp number.

So You need to convert scientific notation to string which will auto include , hence you also need to replace those commas

```
$n = 10000000000000000000001;
$n = str_replace(",", "", number_format($n));
```

Comment: I know the reason, just looking for a solution.

Comment: never define the type of $n and it will always be a string ...if taking inputs from ... you ca't typecast

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn't return the exact value. In your case it returns `10000000000000000000000`

Comment: yah doing this we loose precision .. So its a strict warning on php.net to use string for big numbers