# PHP -- Convert string to bigint

Tags: php

I have the following string which i need to convert to integer or bigint.

```
$test="99999977706";
```

I tried:

```
echo (int)$test;
echo (integer)$test;
echo intval($test);
```

But they are all returning me 2147483647.

How do i convert the above string to a number or bigint?

Many many thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211345/working-with-large-numbers-in-php

Comment: Does it need to be an int or just a number? Because (platform dependent) casting to `(float)` may work.

Comment: I need it to be an int for mysql comparison purposes

Comment: One workaround which works for me was casting to `float`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that number? A usual integer cannot be larger than that value, and BigInt is not built in into PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL isn't going to know the difference. Just feed the string into your query as though it is a number without first type casting it in PHP.

For example:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $test";
```

Comment: Hello @Treffynnon, How it I have to pre process the bigint before the SQL. Let's say I have to use `select ... where ... in ( some bigint values )` ?

Comment: @Cauliturtle I have no idea what you are asking, but I suggest that you ask your own question on StackOverflow as comments aren't really designed for this kind of discussion.

Comment: Can you share more details about this? There is no connection to MySQL in the question, and whatever you want to do with the given ` $SQL` variable, you should not use it to run a query

Answer (score 1):

working solution :

```
<?php
   $str = "99999977706";
   $bigInt = gmp_init($str);
   $bigIntVal = gmp_intval($bigInt);
   echo $bigIntVal;
   ?>
```

It will return : 99999977706

Answer (score 1):

You can treat the string as string without converting it.

Just use a regex to leave only numbers:

```
$test = "99999977706";
$test = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $test);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet $test is already a number, more specifically a float. PHP will convert the contents of $test to the correct type when you use it as a number or a string, because the language is loosely typed.

Comment: Sorry,i modified it. $test is in fact a string and i need it to be a number for comparison purposes

Comment: If you cast it to a float you should be good to go. Mysql has no knowledge of php types so you should be fine casting it to a float and then using it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary length integers use [`GMP`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.gmp.php).

Comment: ...probably the best solution but it should be pointed out that the GMP extension has to be installed or your gmp_init, gmp_intval etc. calls will fail!

Answer (score -1):

It can help you,

```
$token=  sprintf("%.0f",$appdata['access_token'] );
```

you can refer with this [link](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/01/10/php-vs-bigint-vs-float-conversion-caveat/)

Comment: "Help" to achieve what? `sprintf` will never return a BigInt, but always a string