# PHP wrong int conversion

Tags: php

I have been browsing through other "wrong int conversion" problems but I haven't found any posts related to mine.

I am converting a 10 char string (e.g '9052000000', '9056699999' ) to to type int, but I keep on getting the value 2147483647

my code looks something like this: 
             $min = '9052000000';
             $min = (int) $min;

Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP -- Convert string to bigint](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8973988/1503018)

Comment: 2147483647 is the maximum value of a 32-bit integer.

Comment: echo PHP_INT_MAX; and you can see the largest integer supported by your system.

Answer (score 0):

int length is depend on your system 32bit or 64bit.

Please read the manual for this:

[PHP Manual] http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score 0):

You simply hit the limit of integer. Use [`GMP`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.gmp.php) for abitrary length integers.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the manual for this:

[PHP Manual] https://www.php.net/intval