# Add 20% tax to amount

Tags: php, math

I have a amount without 20% Tax in my country.. For example, 12,24 € it s without tax and 14,70 EUR it's with a TAX.

How can I add 20% to 12.24 EUR Amount in PHP?

My script is:

```
<? echo round($cena*(20/100)+$cena, 2);?>
```

But with this script is amount with TAX 14,40 EUR and in real it is 14,70 EUR.
Where is problem? And numbers with zero at start it don't calulcate.. It will show 0,- EUR.

Thanks.

Comment: Why so difficult just do: `12.24 * 1.20`

Comment: Basic math, 2nd grade. Pls.

Comment: `20/100` is most likely treated as integers, and rounded down to `0`

Comment: Isn't the amount plus 20% only 14.688? Don't overcharge.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114861/php-adding-2-decimal-points-numbers-money-gives-wrong-results-in-total-amount. And btw 1.2 x 12.24 = 14.69

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325363/converting-a-number-with-comma-as-decimal-point-to-float

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
 $num = 12.24;
 $percentage = 20;
 $num += $num*($percentage/100);
 $num = round($num, 1);      // 4
 $num = sprintf('%0.2f', $num);
 echo $num;
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, just multiply that number by 1.2. So:

```
<?php echo round($cena * 1.2, 2); ?>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

if you use calculator to solve it, 14.70 is correct. to get 14.40

```
<?php echo round($cena * 0.18, 2); ?>
```

0.18 is 18%

Comment: Your observation is correct, but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

> But with this script is amount with TAX 14,40 EUR and in real it is 14,70 EUR. Where is problem?

The problem is with the format of your input, `12,24`. It is treated as `12`. This is probably because PHP expects the decimal point to be `.` and not `,`.