# Byte to gigabyte conversion not working

Tags: php, math

Trying to convert 9769712680 Bytes to Gigabytes. I have the following code:

```
$value = 9769712680 / (1024 * 1024 * 1024);
```

This should give a value of 9 Gb but instead it gives 2047 Mb (or 2 Gb).

Also tried: `9769712680 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024` but this also does the same thing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you on a 64-bit or 32-bit system? The max integer size on a 32-bit system is 2147483647, or about 2G.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211345/working-with-large-numbers-in-php ?

Comment: This should still work though, PHP represents numbers outside the bounds of a signed int with a float. I've just tried `echo 9769712680 / (1024 * 1024 * 1024);` on a Windows system using a 32-bit build, and it results in the expected `9.0987...`. Can you show where you obtained the data from? Avoid casting anything to an integer, as this will trim the value back into bounds.

Answer (score 5):

`9769712680` - you have integer overflow here, so it becomes `2^31`, the max int value.

Comment: im on a 64bit system , data is from a XML file using foreach to load the value and then $value = 9769712680 / (1024 * 1024 * 1024);

Comment: @user2080473 What is exact type of number? It is very clear that you get somehow max int32 instead of your number.

Comment: 9769712680 is axact number

If i do $value=$test;
echo "$test" I get the number 9769712680

Comment: @user2080473 your code returns 9.something: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/eqs-nnx so you are missing something here.

Comment: what can i miss if its pretty straight forward...
value = 9769712680 / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)

Comment: @user2080473 open my link and see what you miss. Your code produces correct output, not the one you mention in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the initial number is represented as a `int32`.  Doing some math (using Matlab):

```
9769712680/(1024*1024*1024) = 9.09875396639109

double(int32(9769712680))/(1024*1024*1024) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is not represented right (it does work for me).
Anyway you can use the [BC Math library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php), which is commonly compiled with PHP, to solve equations with numbers of any length.

In your case it would look like this:

```
$value = bcdiv('9769712680', '1073741824', 4); /// 1024^3=1073741824
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [BCMath library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php):

```
$bytes = '976971268097697126809769712680976971268097697126809769712680';
$Gb = bcdiv($bytes, bcpow(1024, 3), 2);
echo $Gb; // 909875396730096197509923682250992368225099236822509.92
```