# why pow(3^47) gives wrong answer?

Tags: php

using php, this code `echo sprintf('%.9F',pow(3,47));` outputs `26588814358957501972480.000000000`

where as other sites like [this](http://comptune.com/calc.php?methos=GET&base1=10&base2=10&S1=3&S2=47&func=bcpow&base3=10&places=500) gives `3^47 = 26588814358957503287787`. Is there any bug with PHP? How to resolve it?

btw, i'd like to know what is the maximum digit php can handle for calculation using pow,sprintf,fmod. Is it 300 digits?

Comment: This probably comes from the conversion to float (representation issues).

Comment: @ComFreek Can u please find an alternative for me?

Comment: See [Working with large numbers in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211345/working-with-large-numbers-in-php)

Comment: It's a bug in computers: they have this stupid default habit of working in binary rather than in decimal unless you explicitly tell them to use decimal

Comment: @MarkBaker: It's not a "bug", it is a "feature"!

Comment: Answer to your question about maximum digits depends whether you're talking about 32-bit PHP or 64-bit PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an external program or a PHP extension (library).

I've just tested it with [BC Math](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) and [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) using the [bcpow()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcpow.php)/[gmp_pow()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-pow.php) functions and it works perfectly:

```
<?php

// both output 26588814358957503287787
echo bcpow('3', '47');

echo gmp_strval( gmp_pow('3', '47') );
```

The PHP.net documentation has a nice section about that topic:

> #### Floating point precision
>
> Floating point numbers have limited precision. Although it depends on
>   the system, PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision format,
>   which will give a maximum relative error due to rounding in the order
>   of 1.11e-16. Non elementary arithmetic operations may give larger
>   errors, and, of course, error propagation must be considered when
>   several operations are compounded.
>
> Additionally, rational numbers that are exactly representable as
>   floating point numbers in base 10, like **0.1** or **0.7**, do not have an
>   exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is
>   used internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they
>   cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a
>   small loss of precision. This can lead to confusing results: for
>   example, **floor((0.1+0.7)*10)** will usually return **7** instead of the
>   expected **8**, since the internal representation will be something like
>   **7.9999999999999991118...**.
>
> So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not
>   compare floating point numbers directly for equality. If higher
>   precision is necessary, the [arbitrary precision math functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) and [gmp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php)
>   functions are available.
>
> For a "simple" explanation, see the [» floating point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/) that's also
>   titled "Why don’t my numbers add up?"
>   
>   — http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Note that the [php.ini configuration value 'precision'](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#110766) can also modify the precision when converting from floats to strings.

Answer (score 1):

[**`bcpow()`**](http://php.net/bcpow) (a function of the [**BCMath Arbitrary Precision Mathematics**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) library) can be used in this case.

```
echo bcpow('3', '47'); //as mentioned in ComFreek's answer
//outputs 26588814358957503287787
```

The reason why `pow` isn't work here is because `pow()` uses `float`, and there's a size limitation for `float`.

See this excerpt from the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php):

> The size of a float is platform-dependent, although a maximum of ~1.8e308 with a precision of roughly 14 decimal digits is a common value (the 64 bit IEEE format)

In other words, the maximum possible size may vary -- i.e. (may be different for 32-bit, and 64-bit systems).

Hope that answers your question!