# String number to integer not working PHP

Tags: php, string, integer, msisdn

I am trying to get a string number to an integer but it's not working as expected here is the code with the problem:

```
$usage['msisdn'] = "46720000000";
$usage['msisdn'] = (int)$usage['msisdn'];

echo $usage['msisdn'];
```

It echoes 2147483647 as integer but I want to get 46720000000 as integer.
What's wrong?

By the way I'm parsing the data using json_encode();

---

**UPDATE:** ***Nevermind I've got it to work with intval()***

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211345/working-with-large-numbers-in-php

Comment: I used intval() and it works now thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the maximum value of `int32` is [2,147,483,647](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647_(number)). Your phone number exceeds this value.

You can find the maximum value of int on your server using:

```
echo PHP_INT_MAX;
```

I think that storing a phone number as integer is a bad practice and it may affect you later. Why? Because the phone number may start with:

- **IDD**: `00` or `+`
- **NDD**: `0`

Also, you may want to format the phone number at some point, storing it as string making this part much easier.

*Christmas bonus :)* [libphonenumber-for-php](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php)

Comment: How can I fix this then??

Comment: The only way is to upgrade the server to a 64 bits OS and HW. I suggest you to keep to phone numbers as strings. In fact, the phone number is a string, because it may start with IDD `00`, `+` or NDD `0`, or the country code may start with `0` as well. Also, saving it as string may help if you want to  format the phone number.

Comment: Edited my answer, just above, since you cannot modify the max_int value easily, you could try to use a conversion to float instead.

Comment: Thank you @MateiMihai I didn't know it's better to store tel. numbers as strings. Now I will just let it be a string :)

Comment: Thank you also for the Christmas bonus ;) @MateiMihai

Answer (score 4):

Your code isn't working because the conversion string to int as a maximum value based on your system as quoted in the documentation :

> The maximum value depends on the system. 32 bit systems have a maximum signed integer range of -2147483648 to 2147483647. So for example on such a system, intval('1000000000000') will return 2147483647. The maximum signed integer value for 64 bit systems is 9223372036854775807.

Source : http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Since you cannot modify the max_int value easily, you could try to use a conversion to float instead.

```
$usage['msisdn']  = floatval($usage['msisdn']);
```