# Discord permissions fields in PHP

Tags: php, discord, permissions, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I have to check permissions for each guild of the current logged in user.

I tried this but it does not works because PHP convert string to int, and if it is too large, it will not be the right number.

```php
/* Deprecated: Implicit conversion from float-string "..." to int loses precision */
if ($g->permissions & 0x20) {
    # ...
}

/* Always FALSE if $g->permissions is bigger than php max integer value */
if (intval($g->permissions) & 0x20)
{
    # ...
}
```

And I tried this, but it returns a string (mostly `"02"`, `"10"`, `"12"` and `"20"`) and I don't know what to do with it.

```php
if ($g->permissions & strval(0x20)) {
    # ...
}
```

I searched a lot but can't find anything.
Does someone have a solution to my problem ? Thanks

Comment: As you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/connect/php/default-php-data-types?view=sql-server-ver16) the smallint is converted to int in PHP

Comment: @vinceAmstoutz I don't really understand why you are saying that

Comment: What type does the statement `$g->permissions` return?

Comment: A permission string: for example "4398046511103" where the user is admin;
https://discord.dev/topics/permissions

Comment: Ok and if I understand well you don't use the official api `discord-php/DiscordPHP` ?

Comment: No, I make requests directly

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/211548/14632769) can help you so. Otherwise I freeze ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to make bitwise operations on big integers using [GMP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) ([gmp_and](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_functions_gmp_and.htm)).

Instead of doing:

```php
if ($g->permissions & 0x20) {
    # ...
}
```

I should do:

```
if (gmp_and($g->permissions, 0x20)) {
    # ...
}
```

<sub>Thanks to [@vinceAmstoutz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14632769/vinceamstoutz)</sub>